# How do I escape a special character in fontconfig?

Tags: fonts, debian, inkscape, fontconfig

I am executing Inkscape from the command line to convert SVG to PDF, and I rely on fontconfig to match the font-family of text elements in the SVG to the font files on the (Debian) machine. This works except when the font-family value of the text element's style property contains a period (.). For example, a text element in the SVG has a style value of:

```
font-family: Lobster1.4
```

In the PDF Inkscape exports, this element renders in the default font, not Lobster. So I add a rule to /etc/fonts/local.conf:

```
1  <match target="pattern">
2     <test qual="any" name="family">
3         <string>Lobster1.4</string>
4     </test>
5     <edit name="family" mode="assign">
6         <string>Lobster 14</string>
7     </edit>
8     <edit name="style" mode="assign">
9         <string>Regular</string>
10    </edit>
11 </match>
```

Then I run fc-cache, convert using Inkscape as before, and still the text element does not render in Lobster.

BUT If I change the style value in the SVG for this element to:

```
font-family: Lobster14
```

and change line 3 above to:

```
3         <string>Lobster14</string>
```

the text element renders perfectly, in Lobster. So it's the period (the dot) character that is causing the issue. Unfortunately, the business process I am working on forbids me to alter the SVG input so I have to deal with the period. But how? How do I escape the dot on line 3? This does not work:

```
3         <string>Lobster1\.4</string>
```